# Laravel Microsoft Sql Server connection error

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5, sqlsrv

I get the following error and I don't know why:

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (08001)  SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

**.env** contains

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=server\name
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=mydatabasename
DB_USERNAME=dbusername
DB_PASSWORD=dbuserpassword
```

**database.php**

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'), 
    'connections' => [ 
    'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'server\name'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mydatabasename'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'dbusername'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'dbuserpassword'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'pooling' => false,
        ],

    ],
```

The error is thrown in the UserController.php on this line in the submitLogin function:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['user_name'=>$request['user_name'], 'password'=>$request['password']])) {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
```

and the User Model has these fields defined:

```
public $timestamps = false;
protected $table = 'USERS';
protected $primaryKey = 'USER_ID';
```

Also:
I am using php 7.0.23, wamp64bit 3.1.0
with extensions:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll

extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x86.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
```

enabled
[image]

**I should also note that the database is pre existing.**

What can I do or change or fix to get the connection to the server established without error?

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue on the server or user account does not have remote server access in sql server. Can you connect to SQL Server using the user with SSMS?

Comment: @DanielGale Yes I can connect with the user

Comment: After you edit the .env file, you will need to restart the web server for those settings to take effect. Have you followed steps like here? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=28dc3edU2Uc

Comment: @DanielGale Yes I already watched that video and followed the steps.

Comment: Proper 64bit instances of everything?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472648/sqlsrv-for-php-5-6-on-wamp-server

Comment: @DanielGale It shows in phpinfo() page and works with other apps.. just not this laravel app.

Comment: @DanielGale any additional suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I am out of ideas. It looks like you are on the right track, but still seems like something on the server side. Can you create a simple PHP script that connects?

Comment: @DanielGale I did create one and it connected without issue

Comment: @tks.tman Hey, I am currently having the same issue, and was wondering if you had ever resolved the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @dark_knight94 I did get it to work.

Comment: @dark_knight94 I did get it to work. I changed 'port' => '', under the 'sqlsrv' connection in the database.php file. I also changed how authentication was done to this : $serverName = "server\name";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbname", "UID"=>$username, "PWD"=>$password); 
$db_connx= sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($db_connx) {
 $user_id= DB::table('users')->where('user_name', $username)->value('user_id');
 $user = User::find($user_id);
 if($user){ 
  Auth::login($user);
  return true; 
 }
 return false;
} else {
  return false;
}

Answer (score 1):

When using SQLServer as DB server with Laravel, Ifound that the config shouldbe done as following:

1- if the server is configured with default instance like (server01\SQL01) then we should set the DB_PORT to null or empty string ('')

```
DB_GRH_HOSTNAME=127.0.0.1\SQLExpress01
DB_GRH_PORTNUMB=null
```

2- If the server is configured without default instance and should use the TCP/IP port, then we should set the DB_PORT to the tcp/ip port configured on the server

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=1433
```

Hope that help someone